# Get path from inside a JAR File (for system property in selenium)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar, path

I am using Selenium Webdriver in Java for creating accounts from a excel file for a mediawiki software. I am working with eclipse.

When i try to export my project to a runnable jar file, there are some problems.

I have a file named "geckodriver.exe" im my resources folder (projectname/src/resources/geckodriver.exe)

All i want to do is to set a system property for selenium, so the user not have to manually choose the gecko driver file for working correctly with selenium.

This is my actual code, working inside eclipse

```
String filename = "geckodriver.exe";
File geckodriverFile = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
geckodriverPath = geckodriverFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\\resources\\" + filename;
```

And finally i want to set the system property

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckodriverPath);
```

How can i achieve this to work inside a jar file?

Comment: This is a classic path resolution problem with Java. At runtime, the path is relative to the place where the java command (e.g. java -jar MyJar.jar) is run from. the problem is your setting an absolute path hard-coded in the first place. It would be better to read that in from an external configuration file and ship that with your JAR.

Comment: You could alternatively pass it in as a command-line argument to your JAR, though I don't recommend it.

Comment: Do you think this will work with the path like `jar:file:/c://my.jar!/geckodriver.exe`?